# What is the minimum energy needed for the photodisintegration of U-238?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, photons, nuclear-physics

What is the minimum threshold energy needed for a photon to cause photodisintegration in Uranium 238, and how different (in terms of MeV) is this energy needed for photodisintegration from the energy needed for photofission?

Comment: How can you tell 'disintegration' from 'fission'? Have you looked at your local ENDF mirror?

Comment: @JonCuster opposed to creating two relatively smaller products, I want to only knock out an alpha, proton, or neutron.

Comment: OK, well you should go look at the Evaluated Nuclear Data File entries for U-238. There are 5 entries in total. Use "g,*" instead of "n,*" for reaction. Use the help on the main page to get what each reaction cross section covers.

Comment: Hmmmm... Looks like comments don't allow the star symbol in them... That should be "g,star" for gamma doing anything

Comment: @JonCuster You need to escape the asterisks (by using a backslash) `\*`, resulting in \*. Otherwise they are interpreted as Markdown *italics* markers. Alternatively, you can wrap stuff in backticks so that it's interpreted as code, which looks like this: `g,*`