# If I sent a sample of U238 to the upper atmosphere

Tags: nuclear-physics, gamma-rays, isotopes

If I sent a sample of U238 to the upper atmosphere, would the solar gamma rays be sufficient enough to cause photodisintegration and the subsequent production of Np237?

Comment: I guess this is related to your previous question [What is the minimum energy needed for the photodisintegration of U-238?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/771532/) Assuming you managed to find the data for the previous question isn't this just asking what the γ-ray intensity is at the energies required for photodisintegration?

Comment: @JohnRennie Not necessarily. There is no numeric data on the gamma ray observations high above the atmosphere (although many studies say there do exist gamma rays). So essentially, I am asking if the upper atmosphere has solar gamma rays of the strength ~10 MeV that is emitted from the sun in a consistent manner. I am assuming yes based on inferences from aforementioned studies, but I wonder if any of y'all know anything.

Comment: There are no $\gamma$ rays from the _Sun_ at all. It isn't hot enough to emit $\gamma$ rays from its surface, and the $\gamma$ rays emitted by fusion reactions in the core never make it to the surface. There are $\gamma$ rays from space, so you could try Googling for info on them. Actually I guess we may get occasional bursts of $\gamma$ rays from the most violent solar flares, but that would be only occasional.

Comment: @JohnRennie I see. So it would be possible, but not from solar sources, which means I may have to keep the U238 up there for a long time. Thank you!

Comment: For low earth orbit https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.06944 may be useful.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you! Would this also work? https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Picture-of-atmosphere-transparency-for-different-wavelengths-Lon92-The-continuous_fig1_279826498

Comment: @JonCuster Hello Jon, I have run the calculations and see the errors of my ways. I am now investigating a new method called MAGIS. Thank you for all your help, and take care.